# Generic HID access using C# - unable to read all packets

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10, hid

I have a custom HID device (sensor) transmitting data every 1ms.

The data are received at the PC without losing packets, and this is confirmed by analysing USB traffic with USBlyzer. I have written a simple code in C# using WPF to read data under Windows 10 at 1ms update rate. The 16-bit index is included in each packet to check that all packets have been received. Debugging info shows that the program reads all the packets during first 5-10 seconds, sometimes for much longer. However, on many occasions, after first seconds of correct reading, the update rate drops and packets are now detected only every 5 to 10 ms.

Application priority is set to high. When restarting the HID initialization, the normal reading speed returns back for next 5 to 10 seconds.

Is it possible to suggest a way of reading all data without missing individual packets?

Below I included example of the code:

// HID initialization:

```
    private async Task<Boolean> InitHid()
    {
        try
        {
            isHid = false;
            string hidDeviceSelector = HidDevice.GetDeviceSelector(usagePage, usageId, vendorId, productId);

              hidDeviceInformationCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(hidDeviceSelector);
            if (hidDeviceInformationCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                hidDevice = await HidDevice.FromIdAsync(hidDeviceInformationCollection.ElementAt(0).Id, FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
                if (hidDevice != null)
                {
                    // construct a HID output report to send to the device
                    isHid = true;
                    Debug.WriteLine("InitHid ok");

                    if (!isRegInputReportEventsHid)
                    {
                        // Registration  Input Report Events from HID
                        hidDevice.InputReportReceived += HandleInputReportRecieved;
                        isRegInputReportEventsHid = true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            isHid = false;
            Debug.WriteLine("InitHid false err");
        }
        return isHid;
    }
```

// main code to receive data and analyse for missing packets:

```
private void HandleInputReportRecieved(
        HidDevice sender,
        HidInputReportReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        HidInputReport inputReport = args.Report;
        IBuffer buffer = inputReport.Data;
        DataReader dr = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[inputReport.Data.Length];
        dr.ReadBytes(bytes);

        int diffSensor = (unt16)((uint)bytes[4] * 256 + (uint)bytes[5]);

        if (testhid != (diffSensor-1))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Testhid {0} difi {1}; ", testhid, diffSensor);
        }

        testhid = diffSensor;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The library you have mentioned here is quite tricky to get working. You might want to look at using Windows APIs instead. This API was basically built at a time when event based programming was still a thing, and the task based async pattern was not fully fleshed out. If you want to get it working, you basically need to use task completion source to bridge the gap in to task based async territory. What I do is create a new TaskCompletionSource after read:

Code is here: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Hid.Net/blob/master/Hid.Net.UWP/UWPHidDevice.cs

```
        public async Task<byte[]> ReadAsync()
        {
            if (_IsReading)
            {
                throw new Exception("Reentry");
            }

            lock (_Chunks)
            {
                if (_Chunks.Count > 0)
                {
                    var retVal = _Chunks[0];
                    Tracer?.Trace(false, retVal);
                    _Chunks.RemoveAt(0);
                    return retVal;
                }
            }

            _IsReading = true;
            _TaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>();
            return await _TaskCompletionSource.Task;
}
```

Then when the device gets a report, I set the result on the completion source:

```
      private void _HidDevice_InputReportReceived(HidDevice sender, HidInputReportReceivedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (!_IsReading)
            {
                lock (_Chunks)
                {
                    var bytes = InputReportToBytes(args);
                    _Chunks.Add(bytes);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var bytes = InputReportToBytes(args);

                _IsReading = false;

                _TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(bytes);
            }
}
```

However, using base Windows APIs are much easier because you can simply call them using task based async, and then your code will run on all versions of Windows - not just Windows 10. Microsoft will probably upgrade their Hid API in Windows 10 at some point, but meantime, their API is pretty clunky.

Try this:
https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Hid.Net/blob/master/Hid.Net/Windows/WindowsHIDDevice.cs